# Form TextArea Losing Linebreaks

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to repair an existing web form that submits a text area's contents to an external site's shopping cart service.  The textarea is named "adtext" and upon submission it runs a few different scripts to calculate pricing, etc.  It ultimately re-writes the ad content into a value named op31 (which is recognized by the shopping cart).  The cart system recently got updated and it broke our script to convert line breaks in this text area into something that would be retained in that other site.  I've tried looking at other sites, but it's over my head.  I'm not particularly good at this stuff.  I'm sure this isn't, and likely wasn't the best way to do it.  I've seen CSS suggestions but don't understand it enough to actually implement them.

I've stripped out as much code as I comfortably could to clean it up, but still retain the issue.  I'm wondering if someone could assist me with updating this function into something that would convert the "adtext" textarea's line breaks into something usable when written to "op31".

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function ConvertCarriageReturns(textarea, strReplace){     
      document.form.op31.value = escape(textarea.value)
      for(i=0;i<document.form.op31.value.length;i++){      
        if(document.form.op31.value.indexOf("%0D%0A") > -1 ){         
          document.form.op31.value = document.form.op31.value.replace("%0D%0A",strReplace)
        }
      }
    document.form.op31.value = unescape(document.form.op31.value)}
</script>

<form 
  action="https://(cart's url)/addtocart.aspx" 
  method="post" 
  name="form">
  <textarea name="adtext" rows="12"></textarea>
  <input alt="Add To Cart" name="add" 
    onclick="ConvertCarriageReturns(this.form.adtext,'&lt;br&gt;'); 
    return checkwords(this)" src="https://....Add-To-Cart.gif" 
    type="image" /> 
  <input name="item" type="hidden" value="(misc cart parameters" />
  <input name="op31" readonly="readonly" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Comment: Since we have no idea what the back end of the system is, we can't know what are acceptable codes for line breaks in it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. I just left a message with their customer service desk to ask.  I will update here when/if I get a reply.

Comment: So, their customer service people aren't helping me.  But, if I manually type in a <br> tag, it works when submitting the product.  I believe my script did convert carriage returns into <br> tags but that isn't working now.  Is there anything readily obvious to anyone that might be wrong with the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this native PHP function called [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Like this:

```
$text = nl2br(this.form.adtext);
```